# Drawing axis-aligned bounding box (AABB) in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have plotted two vectors (3,3,2), (2,2,1) and want to add an AABB to the first one
to show that the second vector is within the bounds of the first.

Adding `set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 3,3 front` is not working.
So how can I draw the AABB (or a cuboid with a=3, b=3 and c=2)?

Also how can I put the the scale of the y-axis on the left side.

**Still open:**

- Limit scale of y-axis to left side, and scale of x-axis to bottom front
- <strike>Add arrows to x-, y- and z-axis</strike>
- <strike>Delete the second x- and y- axis so that there is just one of each left</strike>

Gnuscript **resource_vec_aabb**

```
set xyplane 0
set grid

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set zrange [0:5]


splot 'resource_vec_aabb.dat' with vectors filled head lw 2
```

Data **resource_vec_aabb.dat**

```
# Gnuplot .dat file for vectors
0   0   0   3   3   2
0   0   0   2   2   1
```

[image: Graph]

**UPDATE**

```
set termoption dashed   #Needs to be set to draw dashed lines

set border 19           #To set axis (1 + 2 + 16). See: set border help
set xyplane 0
set grid
unset key

my_range = 4

set xrange [0:my_range]
set yrange [0:my_range]
set zrange [0:my_range]

set arrow from graph 0,0,0 to graph 1.05,0,0 size screen 0.025,15,60 \
    filled ls 1 linecolor rgb "black"
set arrow from graph 0,0,0 to graph 0,1.05,0 size screen 0.025,15,60 \
    filled ls 1 linecolor rgb "black"
set arrow from graph 0,0,0 to graph 0,0,1.05 size screen 0.025,15,60 \
    filled ls 1 linecolor rgb "black"

set xtic 1
set ytic 1
set ztic 1

# AABB for 3,3,2
set arrow from 3,0,0 to 3,3,0 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 3,3,0 to 3,3,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 0,3,0 to 3,3,0 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 0,3,2 to 3,3,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 0,3,0 to 0,3,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 0,0,2 to 0,3,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 0,0,2 to 3,0,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 3,0,0 to 3,0,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"
set arrow from 3,0,2 to 3,3,2 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "green"

# 2,2,1
set arrow from 2,0,0 to 2,2,0 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 0,2,0 to 2,2,0 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 2,2,0 to 2,2,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 0,0,1 to 2,0,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 0,0,1 to 0,2,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 0,2,1 to 2,2,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 2,0,1 to 2,2,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 2,0,0 to 2,0,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"
set arrow from 0,2,0 to 0,2,1 nohead linetype 2 linecolor rgb "blue"

set view 40,44,1
splot 'resource_vec_aabb.dat' with vectors filled head lw 2
```

**new output**

[image: updated_version]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion to draw your bounding box with vectors and tic labels at the back y-axis. The bounding boxes are plotted instead of tediously drawn by arrows. There is still room for fine tuning.

**Data:** `SO17363018.dat`

```
# Gnuplot .dat file for vectors
0   0   0   3   3   2
0   0   0   2   2   1
```

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>= 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### draw bounding box of vectors
reset

FILE = "SO17363018.dat"
set termoption dashed     # required for gnuplot4.6 for dashed lines

set xlabel "x-axis" rotate parallel
set ylabel "y-axis" rotate parallel
set xyplane 0
set grid x,y
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set border 19
set xtics 1 nomirror
set ytics axis

set for [i=1:3] arrow i from graph 0,0,0 to \
    graph (1.12*(i==1)), (1.12*(i==2)), (1.12*(i==3)) \
    size screen 0.025,15,60 filled ls 1 lc rgb "black"

x0(i,j,k) = ((i==0 ? 0 : i==1 ? k : j)*3+1)
y0(i,j,k) = ((i==0 ? j : i==1 ? 0 : k)*3+2)
z0(i,j,k) = ((i==0 ? k : i==1 ? j : 0)*3+3)

set key noautotitle
set view 61,49, 1.1

splot FILE u 1:2:3:($4-$1):($5-$2):($6-$3) w vec lc rgb "red" lw 2, \
      for [c=0:1] for [i=0:2] for [j=0:1] for [k=0:1] FILE \
      u (column(x0(i,j,k))):(column(y0(i,j,k))):(column(z0(i,j,k))): \
      ((i==0)*($4-$1)):((i==1)*($5-$2)):((i==2)*($6-$3)) \
      every ::c::c w vec nohead ls 2 lw 1.5 lc c+2
### end of script
```

For current gnuplot versions 5.x, the script needs to be adapted slightly and you can be shorten the plot command a bit:

- dashtype can be specified directly via `dt 2`, not via `ls 2`
- one `for` loop less because in 4.6 `lc variable` doesn't seem to work together with `ls 2`.

```
splot FILE u 1:2:3:($4-$1):($5-$2):($6-$3) w vec lc rgb "red" lw 2, \
      for [i=0:2] for [j=0:1] for [k=0:1] FILE \
      u (column(x0(i,j,k))):(column(y0(i,j,k))):(column(z0(i,j,k))): \
      ((i==0)*($4-$1)):((i==1)*($5-$2)):((i==2)*($6-$3)):($0+1) \
      w vec nohead lw 1.5 dt 2 lc var
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]